# C++ SDL2 Programm crashes on switch loop

Tags: c++, crash, switch-statement, sdl-2

I ran in some trouble by "learning" SDL2.
The program just crashes with the "errormodulename" StackHash_0a9e (whatever THAT is), whenever I press a key which is in my switch loop. 
This is the method:

```
 void InputMan::acceptInput(SDL_Event * e,Graphics * g){
std::cout<<"handling input"<<std::endl;
switch(e->key.keysym.sym){
    case SDLK_UP:
    {
    Sprite * s=g->spriteByName("Filip");
    if(s->getRow()==2){
        s->action();
    }
    else{
        s->setRow(2);
        s->rollBack();
    }
    std::cout<<"Key up"<<std::endl;
    break;
    }
    case SDLK_DOWN:
    {
        Sprite * s=g->spriteByName("Filip");
        if(s->getRow()==0){
            s->action();
        }
        else{
            s->setRow(0);
            s->rollBack();
        }
        std::cout<<"Key down"<<std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case SDLK_LEFT:
    {
        Sprite * s=g->spriteByName("Filip");
        if(s->getRow()==1){
            s->action();
        }
        else{
            s->setRow(1);
            s->rollBack();
        }
        std::cout<<"Key left"<<std::endl;
        break;
    }
    case SDLK_RIGHT:
    {
        Sprite * s=g->spriteByName("Filip");
        if(s->getRow()==4){
            s->action();
        }
        else{
            s->setRow(4);
            s->rollBack();
        }
        std::cout<<"Key right"<<std::endl;
        break;
    }
    default:
     break;
    }
 }
```

I thought that the cause could be, that there is something in the cases, which is forbidden in c++ and I just didn't know that, but with the output-debugmethod I found out that the crash is imediately after the break. 
Maybe the problem isn't really me and the SDL but me and C++.

**EDIT**

The debugger says :

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 0x00000190 in ?? ()
```

(if I press the right arrow button. on left it's 0x00000064 on up 0x000000c8 and  on down 0x00000000)
Apparently I have a reference which is pointing on an invalid area.

**EDIT 2:**

@Jarod has gave me the hint, that maybe the Sprite (`Sprite * s=g->spriteByName("Filip");`) is an nullptr but it seems, that it doesn't.
I added an if-statement:

```
 Sprite * s=g->spriteByName("Filip");
    if(s==NULL){
        starter.die("Sprite \"Filip\" not found");//<-closes the program with an error message)
    }
```

But the statement was not triggered.

**INFO**

I don't know if I already said that but the crash comes AFTER the method is completed and BEFORE the next. That is the reson, why I don't posted the main class here, but I think I should...

```
 void Starter::gameLoop(){
 std::cout<<"Entering Gameloop"<<std::endl;
 while(!quit){
    SDL_PollEvent(ev);
    if(ev->type==SDL_QUIT){
        quit=true;
        std::cout<<"successfull end"<<std::endl;
    }
    else if(ev->type==SDL_KEYDOWN){
        input->acceptInput(ev,graphics);//<-- the method I posted already
        std::cout<<"Paint"<<std::endl;//<-- the program crashes before that happens
    }
    else if(ev->type==SDL_KEYUP){
        graphics->spriteByName("Filip")->rollBack();
    }
    graphics->paint();
 }
}
```

I hope YOU can help me to fix that.

**t h a n k   y o u** .

Comment: On which line does the program crash?

Comment: @user2079303 I don't know! It does not say anything but "Progam_name does not work anymore". But as I mentioned ↑up there↑ : the crash is imediately after the break i.e. after the method closes

Comment: *What* doesn't say anything but that?

Comment: @user2079303 Windows. By "crash" I'm meaning this window: [link](http://puu.sh/aC4uj/baa32dd52e.png) It's in german, but I think you should recognize that.

Comment: Well, your next step is to find out the line that crashes the program. (Hint: use a debugger).

Comment: Have you check that `Sprite * s=g->spriteByName("Filip");` is not `nullotr` ?

Comment: No. That would explain, why I can't see this sprite on screen, but my debugger says, that the pointer does not point to the value of nullptr (look at the edit). I think THAT means, that it depends on the key I'm pressing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare `ev` as a pointer. And declare `SDL_Event e` inside of the `gameLoop` method, and then pass it to another functions by value or by reference, it's always done like this in tutorials and books:

```
void InputMan::acceptInput(SDL_Event e,Graphics * g){...}
```

or

```
void InputMan::acceptInput(SDL_Event &e,Graphics * g){...}
```

and use it in your game loop like this:

```
void Starter::gameLoop()
{
    std::cout<<"Entering Gameloop"<<std::endl;

    while(!quit)
    {

    SDL_event e;
    SDL_PollEvent(&e);

    switch(e.type)
    {
     case SDL_QUIT:
       quit=true;
       std::cout<<"successfull end"<<std::endl;
       break;

     case SDL_KEYDOWN:
       input->acceptInput(e,graphics);
       std::cout<<"Paint"<<std::endl;
       break;

     /*another cases*/
    }
    }
}
```

But the problem may be in your graphics class instance. It may be not initialized properly. Always check them on NULL like troyane said, and try to debug all way down to the crash place, it may give you some answers. And I highly encourage you to use smart pointers provided by C++ 11 standard, like `shared_ptr`, instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Great! It really do work if you just change the SDL_Event Pointer to an Object

Comment: @A13XI5 Glad to hear it. Check my code again, unfortunately I did some typos, but now they're fixed. Also pay attention at `SDL_PollEvent(&e);` You should pass `e` by reference here.

Comment: @RusselLedge Just to clarify: in `SDL_PollEvent(&e)`, you pass a pointer to `e`, not a reference to it.

Comment: For objects that are reused inside a loop, you might want to declare them outside (of the `while { }`) so they are constructed just once.

Comment: Usually you check all events in a frame at once, not only just one: `while (!quit) { while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) { /* acceptInput(e) */ } /* do other game loop stuff */ }`. Only one event per frame is too slow for a game.

Comment: @Leonardo Thanks for explanation. Can you please point on some articles/docs, where explained difference between `SDL_PollEvent(&e)`, `if(SDL_PollEvent(&e))` and `while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))` ?

Comment: @RusselLedge Check http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/03_event_driven_programming/index.php. There's not a big difference: SDL_PollEvent returns 1 if there's more events pending, or 0 if no events are pending. The while loop is just to ensure you process them all.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using pointers. Your function's arguments are `SDL_Event * e, Graphics * g`, so before accessing pointers check if it is not NULL. Since, every time you try to dereference NULL-pointer you got crash.